# Unable to export binary data into a csv file using opencsv

Tags: java, binary-data, opencsv

I'm trying to write data retrieved from a DB into a csv file using opencsv.

All the columns of data except the one with type varbinary are successfully written into the resulting csv file.

The code being run is:

......

```
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    ps = con.prepareStatement(SELECT * FROM <view> WHERE StudentId=26284);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("opencsv/StudentPhoto.csv"), 
             DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
    writer.writeAll(rs, true);
```

.......

Can anybody help in determining what I am missing here, which makes the export of a binary value to fail?

Comment: A CSV file is a text file, try to convert your varbinary field to some varchar representation in your query.

Comment: @Berger, converting the binary value resolved my problem. Thank you!.